# iOS: how to filter to my tags on latest app update

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

On the latest iOS app update how do I filter to all unanswered questions matching my favorite tags? This used to be easy but I can't find it now that the sort/filter selector is customizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not properly addressed in 1.4.4.6.  The official steps are:

1. Create a new sort using the + icon.
2. Tap "Filter" and change it to "Unanswered"
3. Tap "Tagged".
4. Using the tag search screen, add all of your favorite tags.  It says "Up to 5 tags" but you can ignore that.
5. Close the tag picker.
6. A new field called "Tag mode" will have appeared.  Change that from "All" to "Any".
7. Save your sort.

Once it's saved, you can rename it by swiping left on it and selecting "Rename".  You can create a copy of it by swiping left and selecting "Duplicate".

Since this can be a pain if you have a lot of favorite tags, one hack you can do is craft a URL of the form [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/**php+or+python+or+javascript**?sort=unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+or+python+or+javascript?sort=unanswered) with your favorite tags, add it as a comment on this answer, tap on it in the app, open the sort picker and save it.

In 1.4.5.0, which will be shipping this week, I will include favorite tags at the top of the tag picker so you can quickly add all of your favorite tags.

> [image: Screenshot showing favorite tags in tag picker]